# How to DROP a database with character '?' in its name?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-drop

Just trying out ubuntu server on my pc and have been testing some commands including mysql. I'm not sure why phpMyAdmin permitted me to create a database like this 'testing?db'. I'm trying to drop this database via SSH but I get this error:

```
mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| phpmyadmin         |
| testing?db         |
| testing_db         |
| wp                 |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE testing?db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?db' at line 1
mysql>
```

I tried creating a database with a '?' in it and it also gives me syntax error. via ssh.
so how do I remove this database?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try:

```
DROP DATABASE `testing?db`;
```

Comment: yes, you can escape your table/fields name with a ` character

Comment: I was going to post the same thing.  Nice.

Comment: It's called the backtick, present on any keyboard, but not in a fixed location. Look somewhere to the top or bottom left.

Comment: oh thanks! :) i've been using the computer for as long as i can remember but never noticed this `backtick` character on my keyboard.

Comment: Isn't it also the "left single quotation mark" ?
 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm

Comment: @Jasmine I think not, the lsqo is a quotation character, while the backtick is actually an accent (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm)